# iOS - how to implement custom table view cell selection/unselection?

Tags: uitableview, ios8, uicollectionview, selection

I'm working with a UITableView, and as far as I understand it has grey or blue selection of rows. **Is there a way to override UITableView cell selection behavior (define a "selected" style)?**

If there is not, would a vertical collection view work as an imitation of a table view with custom selection?

Comment: Sure there is. Override table view will display cell method and set  `selectedBackgroundView` for any given cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the UITableViewCell Class reference, you are limited to:

UITableViewCellSelectionStyle
The style of selected cells.

Declaration
SWIFT

```
enum UITableViewCellSelectionStyle : Int {
    case None
    case Blue
    case Gray
    case Default
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/swift/enum/UITableViewCellSelectionStyle

So you would have to develop your own custom action on selection to change the background color.